# Ajax request not receiving any response

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, error-handling, request

I wrote an ajax function for a small project I'm working on and I can't get it to run the code inside the .done() function. The function should receive a json object from php (I am getting a response via cURL), however it seems like no response is being given. The project is written using SBAdmin 2 (Bootstrap) and jQuery 3.5.1.

This is the ajax part:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
    <script src="../resources/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Core plugin JavaScript-->
    <script src="../resources/vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom scripts for all pages-->
    <script src="../resources/js/sb-admin-2.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#btnLogin").click(function() {
                console.log('clicked');
                var uname = document.getElementById('inpUsername').value;
                var pwd = document.getElementById('inpPassword').value;  
    
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'resources/php/functions/main-functions.php?',      
                    data: "inpUsername="+uname+"&inpPassword="+pwd,
                    dataType: 'json'
                })
                .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                    console.log('Response received:', data); // Log the entire response
                        if (data.status === 'success') {
                            console.log('Authentication successful:', data.message);
                        } else {
                            console.log('Authentication failed:', data.message);
                        }
                })
                .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    console.log('AJAX Error:', textStatus); // Log the error status
                    console.log('Error details:', errorThrown); // Log the error details
                });
    
                $(location).prop('href', '/index.php?view=loggedin');
                location.reload();
            });
        });
```

And this is the php backend:

```
if(!empty($_POST['inpUsername']) && !empty($_POST['inpPassword'])){
    if(authUser()) {
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        die(json_encode(['status' => 'success', 'message' => 'User authenticated']));
    } else {
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        die(json_encode(['status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Invalid credentials']));
    }
}
```

Running the request in the browser shows the code inside the .fail() function being executed. I am also getting a status "NS_BINDING_ABORTED"

Has anybody got an idea where I'm missing something?

I'm a newbie btw:)

I already changed the ajax function from success and error to done and fail - no effect.
Also I tried manually running the request using devtools - works in cURL but not in the browser.
I rearranged the part where jQuery is being included (before or after the ajax part) - no effect.

Comment: You call `location.reload();` before the call comes back....

Comment: unsure what `$(location).prop('href', '/index.php?view=loggedin');` is doing....

Comment: move `location.reload()` inside of the `$.ajax.done` function. Ajax calls are asynchronous, which means they don't necessarily finish before the next line of code is executed. This is known as a race condition.

Comment: But...what is the point of using ajax if you're just going to reload immediately afterwards anyway? The entire reason ajax exists to to enable web pages to avoid having to do a full refresh just to interact with the server.

Comment: @epascarello I used location.prop() to redirect to the correct view. As php is already checking if a session is present and redirects you to the correct one, that part could be removed.

Comment: @ADyson I use ajax to be able to mamipulate the view to show an error in case the user is using wrong credentials. I used smarty for the first time and figured that would be the easiest way.

Comment: @Luigi yes, although if you posted the form back the server could respond with an error too, if there was a problem, and just echo it to the page. Both ways are fine, just be aware that with the AJAX request followed by a redirect, you end up using two HTTP requests instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue was fixed!

Wow thanks for the help!
I think moving the `location.reload()` inside `$ajax.done()` did the job.

However I implemented all the other suggestions as well. That should make it look a bit cleaner I guess.

**The fixed code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#btnLogin").click(function() {
                var uname = document.getElementById('inpUsername').value;
                var pwd = document.getElementById('inpPassword').value;  
    
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '../resources/php/functions/main-functions.php?',      
                    //data: "inpUsername="+uname+"&inpPassword="+pwd,
                    data : {
                        inpUsername: uname,
                        inpPassword: pwd
                    },
                    dataType: 'json'
                })
                .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                    console.log('Response received:', data); // Log the entire response
                        if (data.status === 'success') {
                            console.log('Authentication successful:', data.message);
                        } else {
                            console.log('Authentication failed:', data.message);
                        }
                        location.reload();
                })
                .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    console.log('AJAX Error:', textStatus); // Log the error status
                    console.log('Error details:', errorThrown); // Log the error details
                });
    
            });
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Besides the issues people pointed out in the comments, I think you might be pinging a wrong url. Your other assets use this path:

```
../resources/foldername etc
```

While your AJAX targets this one:

```
 url: 'resources/php/functions/main-functions.php?',
```

As you can see, the ***resources*** folder in AJAX doesn't have ".."(two dots) in front of it.

Unless you have another ***resources*** folder in the root folder, you should probably be using this url:

```
url: '..resources/php/functions/main-functions.php?',
```

Also, just a nitpick, but since you are sending a POST request, not GET, it would probably be better practice to not use query params. I would personaly go with something like this instead:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '..resources/php/functions/main-functions.php',
    data: {
        inpUsername: uname,
        inpPassword: pwd
    },
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

Comment: Thank‘s for the solution. It seems to be working using both urls, I now switched it to the one you suggested.